# Can I Switch Same Model of Motherboard in Computer Without Needing to "Reactivate" Windows 7 Home Premium OEM and Office 10?

Tags: windows, windows-7, microsoft-office, software-activation

I have an HP 500-164 desktop computer with some broken USB ports.  I found a replacement of the exact same motherboard that I could purchase and "switch out" with the old; however I am concerned about the potential that my Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition (OEM edition)" software, and also my "Microsoft Office 2010" software will need to be "re-activated", once I make the switch.  Will the Microsoft software likely recognize the newly installed motherboard as the exact same model, thus not requiring "re-activation", or is there a potential for me to run into problems that would require "reactivation" of the Microsoft software products?  Thanks so much for your help. -Cfguy

Comment: Only way to know is to try, I doubt you will have an issue activating W7. There should be a COA label on that HP with a Product key should you need one.